# Using comment view modes

Tags: 8, comments, entities

I can use the UI to create a new view mode for a comment type in Drupal 8, without problems, but I don't see how to use that view mode.

For example, I just want to have a *teaser* that shows only the first few lines of each comment, and not the comments on this comment.

How do I specify a particular view mode should be used for the comments on a particular content type?

Does this require Display Suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this without writing your own formatters. However, could you open a feature request in the core issue queue as this is a worthy configuration option for the existing formatter.

Comment: Thanks @larowlan, I opened https://www.drupal.org/node/2627678

Comment: And thanks to the awesome claudiu.cristea, there's already a patch